# Error in opening phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using Windows 7 and had just installed WAMP in it. Then when i tried to open it in my browser i get the following error please help me asap..

> "Error
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server. "

Comment: try updating mysql password in config.inc.php file.

Comment: its null there, and i didn't ever set any :( :(

Answer (score 0):

did you ever use phpmyadmin or mysql console to setup password?

If yes, go to step 6 and follow on

If no, open the file config.inc.php in folder C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin2.10.1 and find this line:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'TakeOutAnythingInThisSingleQuote'; // MySQL password (only needed

Do as advised, then save the file, shut down and exit wamp. After restart wamp, start all over to setup password

Comment: I have already read this same post in a phpmyadmin forum, whether you wrote it or pasted me. thanks but it doesn't helped me.. the problem is still persisting

Comment: after do it , have you restart wamp server?

Comment: :( yupe i did.. but its still there. to add more i am using wamp 2.2, and phpmyadmin version is phpmyadmin3.4.10.1, is there anything to do with this??